# Setting target url with gcloud

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have been using the Google App Engine Launcher's "Deploy" button. I realize that the Launcher is going away at the end of July 2020, so I'm trying to learn to use gcloud. My web site has a custom url, www.xxx.org, but "gcloud app deploy" uploads to xxx.appspot.com instead of to www.xxx.org, presumably because "target url" is set to xxx.appspot.com. Can someone please tell me what gcloud command I need to use to change "target url" to www.xxx.org, or some other scheme that would work? I've wandered through lots of gcloud and GAE documentation and web searches without being able to figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good and complete guide about mapping a custom domain to your application in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains). As @DanCornilescu said,it needs to be configured, but it is not necessary to be done before deployment.

Basically, you need to follow the steps from the guide:

> 1) Verify that you are the owner of your domain through Webmaster
>   Central
>
> 2)Ensure that your domain has been verified, otherwise you will not be able to proceed with the following steps. Note that only verified domains will be displayed.
>
> 3)If you need to delegate the ownership of your domain to other users or service accounts, you can add permission through the Webmaster Central page
>
> 4)After you verify ownership of your domain, you can map that domain to your App Engine app
>
> 5)Add the resource records that you receive to the DNS configuration of your domain registrar
>
> 6)Test for success by browsing to your app via its new domain URL, for example www.example.com

In case you need to do more complex mappings for different urls and subdomains you can always write down the routing rules in the [dispatch.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) and they will be mapped successfully.

Also, to add a bit more of information about the dipatch.yaml file, it will handle the routing in the App as opposed with the app.yaml which will take care of the App's settings. Both .yamls can exist in the same application and can be deployed at the same time by using the following gcloud command:

`gcloud app deploy app.yaml dispatch.yaml`

Comment: Clicking the "Deploy" Launcher button uploads to www.xxx.org, so my problem would not seem to be with such things as DNS. It does seem plausible that I need to have a dispatch.yaml file, about which I've read, but apparently I'm unable to get the syntax right (so I would REALLY appreciate an explicit suggestion) or I'm not using the correct form of the gcloud statement (I tried "gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml") or I don't know whether I have to modify my existing app.yaml file or all of the above, and in what way. It's presumably something utterly trivial, but I can't figure out what to do.

Comment: The way you are deploying the file is correct, as for the syntax, you have a good example in the 2nd link that I shared in my answer. What I would suggest you to do is to check the step 2) from my answer, and be sure that your domain was actually verified. In case it is not displayed in that panel, you will need to do again all the steps that I have mentioned in the answer. You can also edit your question and share your dispatch.yaml file so that I can confirm if you write it properly. Looking forward to hear what you find out about the verification process.

Comment: Seems like I should already be verified, since Launcher "Deploy" works. But I did what you said, and was told that I could not be verified, and then I was told to copy some text into a DNS txt slot, which I did despite the fact that there was indeed already a DNS txt slot with the exact same contents. I'm totally at a loss as to how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know how to write a dispatch.yaml file, though I've tried. When there is one, I'm confused that there's also my long-existing app.yaml file, and I don't know whether it's okay to have two yaml files, and whether one says "gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml" in the presence of two yaml files.

Comment: The syntax reference for the dispatch.yaml file can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#syntax). Also regarding your concern of having two yaml files, there's nothing wrong about that, as their purposes is different, one will handle your App's settings(app.yaml) and the other the routing(dispatch.yaml). You can also deploy both of them at the same time by doing: `gcloud app deploy app.yaml dispatch.yaml`

Comment: Thanks. That did it. And I finally through many experiments found that the dispatch.yaml url setting had to be "xxx.org/" including the final slash, and that when I deploy I will see that the target url is https://xxx.appspot.com. Many thanks for your patience with me!

Comment: Glad to hear that you make it work! I will edit Andrei's answer to add this information! Afterwards, you may consider approving the answer as it might be useful for other people having this same issue

Answer (score 1):

The deployment is always done to `.appspot.com`, the custom domain is automatically updated if it is already configured. If it is not then it needs to be [configured](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) (it can be done after the deployment as well).

Comment: Doesn't the fact that clicking the Launcher "Deploy" button does update xxx.org mean that I have already "configured" my app correctly? I don't see anything in the link you gave (and I've read that text before) that seems to tell me what I need to do. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: If xxx.org was updated it means the config was done, so it should work with gcloud deploy as well. You should see those settings in the developer console: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains